# Creating word games

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-request

Can someone please explain the controversy over my closed [question](https://superuser.com/questions/374708/creating-word-games)?

I followed the FAQ to the letter.

Random's comment: Do something and then ask as question about it. Current format is polling/list for Download.com

I don't understand where in my question it seemed like I was polling, and can't we agree that [this](https://superuser.com/questions/7739/windows-backup-by-imaging) and all other software rec questions are on topic (as long as they follow the [faq](https://superuser.com/faq)).

Comment: Have you tried any tool yet or is this just asking people to throw in what they've used to see what sticks?

Answer (score 2):

It's a question asking about something where nothing is already on the table.

You're looking for programs that fit a checklist and not solutions or answers to a problem that you actually have.

What software can you use? What software have you even tried? Why is that not working? Try something, then come back and ask a question about the tool you're trying to use.

Not a fan of [software-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-rec) questions and will routinely close them for the polls they are. Or for the Softpedia/Download.com lookup pile-on as they otherwise come out to be.

Comment: "You're looking for programs that fit a checklist and not solutions or answers to a problem that you actually have." > So all I need to do is add "I need to make a small word game for a school project.  What software..." ?

Comment: And should I vote-to-close [this](http://superuser.com/questions/7739/windows-backup-by-imaging)?

Comment: Closed the question asking people for opinions. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I should flag all questions tagged the [tag:software-rec] that don't mention everything they've already tried?

Comment: This is not an answer to my question.

Comment: @wizlog a lot of the questions in [tag:software-rec] _are_ low quality and/or off-topic. Your question has been reopened for now, and edited it to improve it a bit, which is good. You seem to misunderstand Meta though - in a discussion post, it's reasonable to post answers such as these with people's ideas. Essentially, the question is the topic of the discussion and the answers are people's responses. Vote up or down for agree/disagree. These are not "not an answer".

Answer (score 1):

I personally think the close action was a little too harsh.

What saves this question is the multilingual support (should be a requirement, not a "nice to have") saves it at the end.

Without that requirement, this would essentially be a LMGTFY.